# The GUI part works, why am i getting "y = x["main"] KeyError: 'main' python"

Tags: python

My main goal is to write a python scrypt that outputs the temperature by inputing your current city.

I made one and im getting this y = x["main"] KeyError: 'main' python. This is using a gui. The gui part works.

I blocked out my api key by the way.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
# import all functions from the tkinter   
#from tkinter import * 
#from tkinter import messagebox * 
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Entry
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import END

messagebox.showinfo("Title", "a Tk MessageBox")

# hide main window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# message box display
messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Warning message")
messagebox.showinfo("Information","Informative message")


# function to find weather details 
# of any city using openweathermap api 
def tell_weather() : 

# import required modules 
import requests

# enter your api key here 
api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# base_url variable to store url 
base_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?'


# take a city name from city_field entry box 
city_name = city_field.get() 

# complete_url variable to store complete url address 
complete_url = (base_url + "appid =" + api_key 
+ "&q =" + city_name) 

# get method of requests module 
# return response object 
response = requests.get(complete_url) 

# json method of response object convert 
# json format data into python format data 
x = response.json() 
print(x)

# now x contains list of  nested dictionaries 
# we know dictionary contains key value pair 
# check the value of "cod" key is equal to "404" 
# or not if not that means city is found 
# otherwise city is not found 

if x["cod"] != "404" : 

    # store the value of "main" key in variable y 
    #if __main__ == '__response.json() __':

    y = x['main'] 

    # store the value corresponding to the "temp" key of y 
    current_temperature = y["temp"] 

    # store the value corresponding to the "pressure" key of y 
    current_pressure = y["pressure"] 

    # store the value corresponding to the "humidity" key of y 
    current_humidiy = y["humidity"] 

    # store the value of "weather" key in variable z 
    z = x["weather"] 

    # store the value corresponding to the "description" key 
    # at the 0th index of z  
    weather_description = z[0]["description"] 

    # insert method inserting the  
    # value in the text entry box.  
    temp_field.insert(15, str(current_temperature) + " Kelvin") 
    atm_field.insert(10, str(current_pressure) + " hPa") 
    humid_field.insert(15, str(current_humidiy) + " %") 
    desc_field.insert(10, str(weather_description) ) 

    # if city is not found                    
    else : 

    # message dialog box appear which 
    # shows given Error meassgae 
    messagebox.showerror("Error", "City Not Found \n"
                         "Please enter valid city name") 

    # clear the content of city_field entry box 
    city_field.delete(0, END) 


    # Function for clearing the  
    # contents of all text entry boxes   
    def clear_all() :  
        city_field.delete(0, END)   
        temp_field.delete(0, END) 
         atm_field.delete(0, END) 
        humid_field.delete(0, END) 
        desc_field.delete(0, END) 

    # set focus on the city_field entry box  
    city_field.focus_set()  


    # Driver code 
    if __name__ == "__main__" : 

# Create a GUI window 
root = tkinter.Tk() 

# set the name of tkinter GUI window 
root.title("Gui Application") 

# Set the background colour of GUI window  
root.configure(background = "light green") 

# Set the configuration of GUI window  
root.geometry("425x175") 

# Create a Weather Gui Application label  

headlabel = Label(root, text = "Weather Gui Application", 
                  fg = 'black', bg = 'red') 

# Create a City name : label 
label1 = Label(root, text = "City name : ", 
               fg = 'black', bg = 'dark green') 

# Create a City name : label 
label2 = Label(root, text = "Temperature :", 
               fg = 'black', bg = 'dark green') 

# Create a atm pressure : label 
label3 = Label(root, text = "atm pressure :", 
               fg = 'black', bg = 'dark green') 

# Create a humidity : label 
label4 = Label(root, text = "humidity :", 
               fg = 'black', bg = 'dark green') 

# Create a description :label 
label5 = Label(root, text = "description  :", 
               fg = 'black', bg = 'dark green') 


# grid method is used for placing  
# the widgets at respective positions  
# in table like structure .   
headlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)  
label1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky ="E")  
label2.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky ="E")  
label3.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky ="E")  
label4.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky ="E")  
label5.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky ="E") 


# Create a text entry box  
# for filling or typing the information.  
city_field = Entry(root)  
temp_field = Entry(root)  
atm_field = Entry(root)  
humid_field = Entry(root)  
desc_field = Entry(root) 

# grid method is used for placing  
# the widgets at respective positions  
# in table like structure .  
# ipadx keyword argument set width of entry space .  
city_field.grid(row = 1, column = 1, ipadx ="100")  
temp_field.grid(row = 3, column = 1, ipadx ="100")  
atm_field.grid(row = 4, column = 1, ipadx ="100")  
humid_field.grid(row = 5, column = 1, ipadx ="100")  
desc_field.grid(row = 6, column = 1, ipadx ="100") 

# Create a Submit Button and attached  
# to tell_weather function  
button1 = Button(root, text = "Submit", bg = "red",  
                 fg = "black", command = tell_weather) 

# Create a Clear Button and attached  
# to clear_all function  
button2 = Button(root, text = "Clear", bg = "red",  
                 fg = "black", command = clear_all) 

# grid method is used for placing  
# the widgets at respective positions  
# in table like structure .  
button1.grid(row = 2, column = 1) 
button2.grid(row = 7, column = 1) 

# Start the GUI  
root.mainloop()
```

Im also getting this :

{cod 401, message Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/ faq #error401 for more info.} Exception in Tki

I Know i am using the correct api key. maybe i am missing something.
Excuse my formatting of the code. This is the first time I use stackoverflow.

This is python language btw.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem earlier on , but then i realised it was just a bone headed mistake
In this line ,

```
....
complete_url = (base_url + "appid =" + api_key 
+ "&q =" + city_name) 
....
```

there should be no spaces between any of the characters , otherwise %20 will be inserted automatically by the browser to fill the gap , thus messing with api key . So change it to:

```
....   
complete_url = (base_url + "appid=" + api_key 
+ "&q=" + city_name)             ↑
.... ↑
```

The only changes I've made is removed the extra spaces
(The arrows indicate the changes made .)
Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

The error message is fairly clear. It is saying that in this bit of code:

```py
if x["cod"] != "404" : 

    # store the value of "main" key in variable y 
    #if __main__ == '__response.json() __':

    y = x['main']
```

You try to look up the key `'main'` in the dictionary `x` but that key is not in the dictionary `x`.